# Dynamically show/hide input with shinyjs and flexdashbord

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs, flexdashboard

Trying to update **Sidebar** in **flexdashboard** when click on a tab. Can't get it to work.

````
---
title: "Test Sidebar"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
     orientation: rows
 runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)
```
Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=250}
=======================================================================

```{r}
div(id = "one", selectInput("input1",label= "Show Always",choices=c("a","b","c")))    
div(id = "two",selectInput("input2",label = "Show only on Tab 1", choices=c("d","e","f")))
```

<!-- Update the sidebar based on the tab chosen. Generated HTML code shown for tabs-->

Tab 1 <!-- <a href="#section-tab-1" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="tab"> -->
=======================================================================
```{r}
useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)
shinyjs::onclick("#section-tab-2",shinyjs::hide(id = "two"))
shinyjs::onclick("#section-tab-1",shinyjs::show(id = "two"))
```

Tab 2 <!-- <a href="#section-tab-2" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="tab"> -->
=======================================================================
```{r}
useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)
actionButton("hideSlider", "Hide Input Two")
observeEvent(input$hideSlider, {
     shinyjs::toggle(id = "two", anim = TRUE)
    })
```
````

Works okay with actionButton() and observerEvent().  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Try adding an 'id' to your links and call that id in the `onclick` instead.

Answer (score 3):

A few comments:

- You only need to call `useShinyjs()` once, no need to call it in every code chunk
- `onclick()` takes the ID of the element. Not the selector - the ID. This means that you call `onclick("element")` rather than `onclick("#element")`
- If you look at the HTML that gets generated by the dashboard, you'll see that there is no element with id "section-tab-2", so what you're trying to do won't work
- In regular shiny apps, when I use a `tabsetPanel()`, the way I do what you're trying to do is by using the value of the selected tab. Whenever a tab is selected, there's an input value that gives you the value of what is selected. I haven't used flexdashboard extensively so I'm not sure if there's a similar way to get the value of the selected tab in a flexdashboard.

Comment: Thanks @daattali for the input. I have searched around and at the moment i don't think is relatively straightforward to solve with flexdashboard.